# Cant fint element using XPath - NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

im trying to find element using Selenium web driver in c#.
my code is:

```
var pathToLinkGeneral = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-control'][label[text()='Get direct link:']]/input"));
```

the source code in page is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Get direct link:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" style="cursor: auto; value="http://ds2.dev.polebeary.com/api/download/1521723231257836/qa_yaakov_tevel.dmg" readonly="">
```

but i keep getting this exception-

```
Message: Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='form-control'][label[text()='Get direct link:']]/input"}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: the div has class `form-group`, not `form-control`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
var pathToLinkGeneral = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group'][label[text()='Get direct link:']]/input"));
```

You need form-group, not control.